# Python Jupyter - Crawling eBay website , nested try & except ERROR

Tags: python, try-catch, jupyter, try-except

im trying to get the PRICE from 1000 pages in eBay, but i have 3 different of ID tag to the Price. I'v tried few options but i got "IndentationError" , or when i got the output.csv , got a A column of empty cells.

```
def get_detail_data(soup): # Price

try:
    try:
        try:
        p = soup.find('span', id='prcIsum').text.strip() ##Rid off the spaces,also split the string by space                        
    except:
        p = soup.find('span', id='prcIsum_bidPrice').text.strip()
    except:
        p = soup.find('span', id='mm-saleDscPrc').text.strip()
    except:
             
    currency , price = p.split(' ') ##to get 2 elements
except:  
    currency = ''
    price=''
```

Answer (score 0):

The indentation levels of the **try** and **except** need to be matched.

This should fix the indentation error, though I am not sure if it will make the code do what you want:

```
try:
    try:
        try:
            p = soup.find('span', id='prcIsum').text.strip() ##Rid off the spaces,also split the string by space                        
        except:
            p = soup.find('span', id='prcIsum_bidPrice').text.strip()
    except:
        p = soup.find('span', id='mm-saleDscPrc').text.strip()
             
    currency , price = p.split(' ') ##to get 2 elements
except:  
    currency = ''
    price=''
```